# gitlab-CI for a Haskell Stack project: How to cache built libraries?

Tags: haskell, gitlab, gitlab-ci, ghc, haskell-stack

I'm using the following `.gitlab-ci.yml` file for setting up gitlab-CI for a Haskell Stack project created with `stack new actividad3 --resolver=lts-14.6`.

```
image: haskell:8.6.5

cache:
  paths:
    - .stack
    - .stack-work
    - target

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ghc --version
    - stack --system-ghc build
    - stack test
```

Building and testing the project last almost 5 minutes. Most of the time is spent building the hspec library. Is there any way to cache the used libraries between pipeline runs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MarkSeemann If you look at the question details you'll note that they put `.stack-work` into the cache option of their CI config, they're asking why that's apparently not enough to reliably cache dependencies between CI runs/different stages of the same pipeline

Comment: Make sure to pass the `stack --system-ghc test` when running tests, also you don't need to run a separate `stack build`, `stack test` does building already.

Answer (score 7):

Add these parts to your `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
variables:
  STACK_ROOT: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.stack-root"

cache:
  paths:
    - .stack-work/
    - .stack-root/
```

The `$STACK_ROOT` env variable changes the folder stack uses for it's global files. This is required because GitLab CI can only cache files under the project folder, so caching `$HOME/.stack`, `~/.stack` or `/root/.stack` won't work.

A few relevant references from the web:

- http://blog.braulio.me/2018/10/24/use-haskell-stack-gitlab-ci.html;
- https://vadosware.io/post/zero-to-continuous-integrated-testing-a-haskell-project-with-gitlab/
- https://dev.to/drbearhands/haskell-for-madmen-setup-4cj9
- https://github.com/bitemyapp/haskell-continuous-integration/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: I also had to chown the parent folder, stack complains a lot when the stack root folder is owned by a different user than the parent folder of the stack-root folder, fwiw.

Answer (score 2):

Most important for proper caching of a stack project is saving all folders being involved:

- Project work directory (or many directories if it is a multi-package setup), usually `.stack-work`
- Global stack directory, usually `~/.stack`
- Possibly a separate folder with binaries (ghc, ghc-pkg, ...)

These can vary between the operating systems and customized with environment variables, but can be easily discovered by asking `stack` itself. Run `stack path` within a stack project and you'll see all of the paths that stack might care about. These are the ones you'll need to cache and restore on CI in order to prevent recompilation:

- `stack path --stack-root`
- `.stack-work` directories in all of the packages within the project (paths from 
  `packages` in `stack.yaml`)
- on Windows `stack path --programs`

Just in case, if you want to see how this stuff can be derived programmatically from Haskell itself, you can find it [here](https://github.com/fpco/cache-s3/blob/master/src/Network/AWS/S3/Cache/Stack.hs)

I wrote this tool called [`cache-s3`](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2018/02/cache-ci-builds-to-an-s3-bucket) a while back that allows you to use an AWS S3 bucket as cache for your CI and it has separate mode that will save and restore all of the stack related directories. This is probably an overkill for a simple project, so the gitlab's caching mechanism will likely be sufficient, but in case you need it is an option.