# What does Pantry snapshots solve?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I've been assigned a task to speed up a Haskell project build time.
As this is my first contact with building Haskell projects I had to spend couple of days reading, searching and trial and error builds.

Switched from cabal to stack, now trying to figure out how to cache build dependencies using gitlab runner.

I know that the deps are saved to `~/.stack` directory. But runner cannot cache directory outside the project.

I can "hack" my way out of that but looking for more proper solution.

In the Haskell docs I've found part where Pantry snapshots are mentioned. Are snapshots connected to dependency cache at all?

https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/pantry/#snapshots

Comment: "But runner cannot cache directory outside the project." Have you tried `stack --stack-root ./.stack_now_caches_dependency_build_stuff_here`

Comment: Take also a look at my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58018322/1651941