# How to add Stack and GHC on GitLab's Continuous Integration?

Tags: haskell, gitlab, gitlab-ci, ghc, haskell-stack

My CI cant find stack and I don't know why. I'm using the following .gitlab-ci.yml file for setting up gitlab-CI for a Haskell Stack project. I took it from [this other question that claims it worked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58017051/gitlab-ci-for-a-haskell-stack-project-how-to-cache-built-libraries).

```
image: haskell:8.6.5

cache:
  paths:
    - .stack
    - .stack-work
    - target

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ghc --version
    - stack --system-ghc build
    - stack test
```

However it fails and reports (full output below):

```
bash: line 96: ghc: command not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Clearly, ghc is missing, but I though that came on the image `haskell:8.6.5` doesn't it?

I have tried alternative images such as `image: fpco/stack-build:lts-11.15` without any luck (reports `bash: line 96: stack: command not found`).

My best guess is that I'm missing a crucial step to make sure `ghc` and `stack` are on the image I'm using, but I can't figure out what it is. So, what am I missing?

Edit: full error output

```
Running with gitlab-runner 13.2.2 (a998cacd)
  on karson: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Shared q_B8_V-j
Preparing the "shell" executor
00:00
Using Shell executor...
Preparing environment
00:00
Running on karson...
Getting source from Git repository
00:01
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Initialized empty Git repository in /var/lib/gitlab-runner/builds/q_B8_V-j/0/fromager/cheesecloth/MicroRAM/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out 4d7e065d as 39-continuous-integration...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Restoring cache
00:00
Checking cache for default...
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=4053876 revision=a998cacd version=13.2.2
No URL provided, cache will not be downloaded from shared cache server. Instead a local version of cache will be extracted. 
Successfully extracted cache
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:00
$ ghc --version
bash: line 96: ghc: command not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Comment: Can you post the full output log? Current guess is that it is not using the `haskell:8.6.5` and some other default image, but should say in the top of the logs of the job.

Comment: Added the full output. You might be right, seems like it's not loading Haskell, but I have no idea how to make it do that. I though `image: haskell:8.6.5` was the command to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the output log, you are using the [shell](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/shell.html) executor rather than the [docker](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html) executor, which is why the `image` tag is having no effect here.

---

Options to resolve is to either:

- If you have access to the runner's server, re-install the runner as a `docker` executor (https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html), and ensure you use `tags` to specify which runner to use for the job. (You might not necessarily need to re-install the runner, but to just install the runner alongside the shell runner, but you need to make sure to use `tags` correctly as to whether or not you want to use the shell runner or docker runner).
- Run the docker commands manually as shell (although this one is less ideal).

---

Update: for ensuring you pick the correct runner for the job:

When [registering](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/) the runner, at step 5, you can provide tags associated with the runner. You can also change the tags in the GitLab UI if you have sufficient permissions in:

```
gitlab.com -> group -> settings -> CI/CD -> runner settings
```

Note, the runner tags are not changeable in the config.toml file.

You can now, for example, tag your runner with `docker-internal`, and then to run jobs only on this runner, add tags: - `docker-internal` in your gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - ghc --version
    - stack --system-ghc build
    - stack test
  tags:
    - docker-internal
```

Comment: Makes sense, thank you. I have several shared runners, some of which have docker. Is there a way to pick those?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the answer with some more information.

Comment: That did it. Thanks!